# PHP: Convert local monthname to monthnumber

Tags: php, date

How would one go about converting a local name of the month, to the respective month number?

You could just make the translation manually, but I'm pretty sure PHP got some built in functions for this?

```
$monthname = "februar"; // norwegian name for february
$monthnumber = insertCorrectFunctionHere($monthname);
```

The goal is for `$monthnumber` to become '2' here (or '02'), since february is the second month.

Comment: Set the locale correctly for Norway; use [strptime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) to get an array from `1-Februar-2015` and read the `tm_mon` value of that array, adding 1 to that value

Comment: @Kristian Rafteseth Have a look at my answer, i think that it answers your question

Answer (score 1):

Just use the date() function. Use the code below

```
<?php
    $month_number = date('m', strtotime('1 February'));
    echo $month_number; //Prints 02
```

Another way you can do it by making an array. Use the code below

```
 <?php
    $array = array("Januar"=>"01","Februar"=>"02","Mars"=>"03","April"=>"04","Mai"=>"05","Juni"=>"06","Juli"=>"07","August"=>"08","September"=>"09","Oktober"=>"10","November"=>"11","Desember");
    $month_name = "February";
    $month = ucwords(strtolower("Februar"));
    $month_number = $array[$month];
    echo $month_number; // Prints 02
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: For the date() method, if the current day is greater than 28 or 29 on a leap year this will return March. So to over come this use 1st February as the string. Same with months that don't have 31 days.

Comment: it doesnt work with the norwegian month name, even if setting locale to nowegian.

Comment: @Kristian Rafteseth Updated my answer use my second part of the answer

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$date = '1 February';
$month= date('m', strtotime($date));
echo $month;
```

Comment: If the current day is greater than 28 or 29 on a leap year this will return March. So to over come this use 1st February as the string. Same with months that dont have 31 days.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to convert the month to time format using strtotime function

The output of strtotime function can be passed to date function to generate the month in numerical format

you can use the following code

```
        $date = 'january';
        echo date('m', strtotime($date));
```

The output of the above code will be 01 refering to